# DB2 SQLJ - Questions on scrollable cursor

Tags: db2, cursor, fetch, cics, sqljdbc

We have CICS app talk to DB2 on z/os. We were asked to mimic queries call to DB2 from JDBC using SQLJ as CICS uses static sqls. We are able to successfully do selects and cursors with DB2.

Question:
1. **Select statements**: CICS issue fetch message to DB2 but JDBC on a resultset on Block fetch in buffer. Is there any way we can avoid this with JDBC? We would like to mimic same fetch message to DB2 as like CICS.

Comment: ....okay, _why_ are you attempting to mimic some other program/protocol that closely?  Normally you'd just let JDBC do its thing.

Comment: We have a constraint to do Load testing via CICS and would like to mimic via JDBC since the bottleneck is with DB2 CPU time usage. If not JDBC, is there any other alternative approach to achieve this ? (outside of CICS )